# Calligraphic and script fonts with both upper and lower case?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, alphabet

What do I need to do to define a `\mathscr` which can handle both upper and lower case letters *and* a `\mathcal` which can handle both upper and lower case, with the latter staying as close to the default `\mathcal` as possible?

A simple approach with a single `\usepackage` line along with some options supplied would be desirable. Every other solution I run into which involves a `\newcommand`, `makeatletter`, `\newenvironment`, `\setmathfont`, etc., has failed me.

Below, `boondox` was as close as I could get to the existing `\mathcal`. Note that my definition for `scr` did not support lowercase, for some reason.

XeLaTeX/PdfLaTeX make no difference here.

I've gone through a number of posts related to this topic, with none just working for me. I may have an issue with not being able to install font packages correctly? This is mysterious.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[scr=rsfs,cal=boondox]{mathalfa}
\begin{document}
    $$\mathscr{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$$
    $$\mathscr{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST}$$
    $$\mathcal{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$$
    $$\mathcal{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST}$$
\end{document}
```

[image]

UPDATE: This may just be an issue with the `rsfs` font. Replacing my `usepackage` line above with

```
\usepackage[scr=esstix,cal=boondox]{mathalfa}
```

produces results for all four lines. I prefer the `rsfs` fonts to `esstix` and prefer whatever the default `\mathcal` font is to `boondox`. But if no one has another solution, this may just need to be what I go with.

Comment: the computer modern font used for \mathcal, and the rsfs font only have uppercase so one way or another you need to pick a different font, of course some are more or less like those two than others but it's just a matter of personal choice.

Answer (score 1):

The `unicode-math` package supports OpenType math fonts, all of which have lowercase script letters (as well as bold).

By default, the package loads the same font as `\mathcal` and `\mathscr`, but you can override this with `\setmathfont[range={cal,bfcal}, Scale=MatchUppercase]{...}` or `\setmathfont[range={scr,bfscr}, Scale=MatchUppercase]{...}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
% So that the output fits the allowed width on TeX.SX:
\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm]{geometry}

\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
% Unicode uses the same range for `\mathcal` and `\mathscr` letters, but the
% STIX Two font provides a separate script alphabet as Stylistic Set 01.
\setmathfont[range={scr,bfscr}, StylisticSet=1]{STIX Two Math}

\begin{document}
    \[\mathscr{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}\]
    \[\mathscr{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST}\]
    \[\mathcal{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}\]
    \[\mathcal{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST}\]
\end{document}
```

[image: STIX Two font sample]

A few other OpenType math fonts come with separate `\mathcal` and `\mathscr` alphabets, including XITS Math and Asana Math.  You can, however, mix and match however you like.  You could, for example, add

```
\setmathfont[range={cal,bfcal},
                    Scale=MatchUppercase
                   ]{STIX Two Math}
```

or

```
\setmathfont[range={scr,bfscr},
             Scale=MatchUppercase,
             StylisticSet=1
            ]{STIX Two Math}
```

to use the script or calligraphic alphabets above in another document.

There are a handful of legacy NFSS math script fonts that come in lowercase.  For example, `stix2-mathscr` does, but `stix2-mathcal` does not. The `mathalfa` package ought to be able to load the lowercase alphabet if it exists; you should not need to load both `mathalfa` and a package such as `mathrsfs`.

Comment: No understanding how to put this all together. Could you add a minimal example?

Comment: @lowndrul Is this better?

Comment: Thanks for sharing the example. Unfortunately, I get an error. When running using `bookdown`, I get the message `! LaTeX3 Error: Command '\setmathfont' already defined!` and when running using XeLaTeX directly I get the error message `"Package fontspec Error: The font "STIX Two Math" cannot be found. \setmathfont`. That's one among many errors. Found people on other boards having similar trouble with `\setmathfont`.

Comment: @lowndrul That’s really a separate question. But to use `\setmathfont` with `bookdown`, you’d use [these options](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#variables-for-latex).