# Writing infinitesimal (differential) element in cursive form

Tags: symbols

I always write dx ,ds dphi dtheta in cursive form and I also wanted to write it in latex .

How can I achieve it?

One of reason(s) that I wanted to do so is that , for instance as we observe ds, then it can be interpreted as d times s however generally ds is a one constant. So I want to remove that ambiguity.

Concretely , I want to connect 2 symbols with a single stroke.

The below left ones are the one-stroked and the right ones are 2-stroked.

[image]

I should have written the bottom left ds with more small s .

Comment: There are plenty of related answers, e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/480924/82917, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/231322/82917, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/491150/82917.

Comment: An upright “d” is frequently used (but the usage is disputable). I have never seen the two letters joined together; can you perhaps show a (printed) source?

Comment: I added the image to my post .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pick a script font of your choice, and build it into the macro `\differential`.  I also chose `newtxmath` because it looked more compatible with the script font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,newtxmath}
\usepackage{aurical}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand\differential[1]{\mkern2mu\text{{\Fontauri d}$\mkern-1mu#1$}}
\begin{document}
\[
\int_0^1 x^2 \differential{x}
\]
\[
\int_0^{\pi/2} \theta^2 \differential{\theta}
\]
\[
\int_0^1 s^2 \differential{s}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a version with `eulervm` for the default math font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,eulervm}
\usepackage{aurical}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand\differential[1]{\mkern2mu\text{{\Fontauri d}$\mkern-1.5mu#1$}}
\begin{document}
\[
\int_0^1 x^2 \differential{x}
\]
\[
\int_0^{\pi/2} \theta^2 \differential{\theta}
\]
\[
\int_0^1 s^2 \differential{s}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As the Latins wrote and they said...

[image]

"There's no disputing on the tastes." or like the comment of the very nice user  *@Steven B. Segletes* "there is no accounting for taste." or  "To each, his own".

I would to use a calligraphic font taken from `mathalfa` package, option `cal`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[cal=boondox]{mathalfa}
\newcommand\dif[1]{\mathcal{d}{\!#1}}
\newcommand\difs[1]{\mathcal{d}{\!\mathcal#1}}
\begin{document}

\[\int^{n}_{i=1}{a_i\log(x)\dif{x}}\]

\[ax\difs{s}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is possibile to use in math mode also using `frcursive` package that you can see the documentation here, https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/fonts/frcursive/frcursive.pdf. But with a lot of humilty I not see a good visual solution.

Comment: The common version of the expression in American English is "there is no accounting for taste."  Another that is nearly equivalent in connotation is "To each, his own".